# Does a javaScript file always have to be named main.js when using it for website?

Tags: javascript

I am making a website for a school project. I am currently linking my sign up page to send information to my firebase database (it works so far). But I was wondering if I could have multiple .js files for the same website in the same folder. I started out with a "main.js" file, linked it to my signUp.html. Then, I thought it would be good to maybe have at least 2 different .js files for this webiste. So I changed the name from main.js to signUp.js (I also made the ref change in the signUp.html), but my page stopped working until I changed everything back to main.js.

Comment: You can call files anything you want.

Comment: No, there's nothing magic about the name "main.js".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser sometimes stores your files in a cache in order to load the files quickly.

Try this:

```
CTRL + F5
```

to refresh invalidating the cache.

The fix is called "hard refresh". this works in most Windows and Linux browsers. In your case, it may be different. Find the right shortcut depending on your environment.